# Insert multiple values from array into mulitple divs in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to insert values from an array into HTML.
The value from the array includes image and alt.

The HTML includes multiple sections like this code below:

```html
<!--section-->
<div class="d-xl-none">
  <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
    <a>
      <img src="###########">
      <div class="caption">
        <p id="captionStyle">NR1 Here should be the alt</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--section-->

<!--section-->
<div class="d-xl-none">
  <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
    <a>
      <img src="###########">
      <div class="caption">
        <p id="captionStyle">NR2 Here should be the alt</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--section-->
```

And the array looks like this:

```js
const imagesArr = [{
  image: 'src nr1',
  alt: 'THIS TITLE SHOULD BE INSERTED TO id="captionStyle"',
},
{
  image: 'src nr2',
  alt: 'THIS TITLE SHOULD BE INSERTED TO id="captionStyle"',
} ];
```

What is the best way to pull the data when I have multiple items and multiple sections in HTML?

I'll try it on my own but I'd be glad for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Although this will be much easier if you used any of the main frontend framework such as Angular, React, Vue, but as you're doing it in plain JavaScript, you could do something like this.

```js
const imagesArr = [{
  image: 'src nr1',
  alt: 'THIS TITLE SHOULD BE INSERTED TO id="captionStyle"',
},
{
  image: 'src nr2',
  alt: 'THIS TITLE SHOULD BE INSERTED TO id="captionStyle"',
} ];

const htmlElements = [];

imagesArr.forEach(image => {
let container = document.createElement('div');
  container.setAttribute('class', 'd-xl-none');
  let thumbnail = document.createElement('div');
  thumbnail.setAttribute('class', 'mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview');
  let anchor = document.createElement('a');
  let img = document.createElement('img');
  img.setAttribute('src', image.image);
  let captionContainer = document.createElement('div');
  captionContainer.setAttribute('class', 'caption');
  let caption = document.createElement('p');
  caption.setAttribute('class', 'captionStyle');
  caption.append(image.alt);
  
  captionContainer.append(caption);
  anchor.append(img, captionContainer);
  thumbnail.append(anchor);
  container.append(thumbnail);
  htmlElements.push(container);
});

const parentContainer = document.querySelector('.parent-container');
parentContainer.append(...htmlElements);
```

```html
<div class="parent-container"></div>
```

Comment: I'll look into it! But is there really no other way to insert just the value for n items into n class or id's?

Comment: From what I understand, the other way will be by querying each node individually, which means you need to have a unique selector for each of them so you can select and then assign the values. Maybe you can assign classes to each of your elements like thumbnail-1, thumbnail-2, thumbnail-n and then in your selector, you could do, document.querySelector('thumbnail-${<index-of-your-image-element>}') and then work with it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the sections and use the idx to grab the values from the array:

```js
const imagesArr = [{
  image: 'https://placekitten.com/200/200',
  alt: 'THIS TITLE SHOULD BE INSERTED TO id="captionStyle"',
},
{
  image: 'https://placekitten.com/200/300',
  alt: 'THIS TITLE SHOULD BE INSERTED TO id="captionStyle"',
} ];

const sections = document.querySelectorAll(".d-xl-none")

sections.forEach((el,idx) => 
{
  el.querySelector("img").src = imagesArr[idx].image
  el.querySelector(".caption p").innerHTML = imagesArr[idx].alt
})
```

```html
<!--section-->
<div class="d-xl-none">
  <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
    <a>
      <img src="###########">
      <div class="caption">
        <p id="captionStyle">NR1 Here should be the alt</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--section-->

<!--section-->
<div class="d-xl-none">
  <div id="firstThumbnail" class="mobileGallery thumbnail d-flex justify-content-center imagePreview">
    <a>
      <img src="###########">
      <div class="caption">
        <p id="captionStyle">NR2 Here should be the alt</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<!--section-->
```